# adding crlf to WCHAR * in VC++ 2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++, newline, wchar

this is VC++ 2005:
How can I append a WCHAR * "firstText" and another WCHAR * "secondText" into another WCHAR * "thirdText" with a CRLF "\r\n" between them?

```
WCHAR firstText [100] = L"First line";

WCHAR secondText [100] = L"Second line";

WCHAR thirdText [500] = L"";
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Prefer `std::wstring` to wide character array. There is no type `WCHAR` in portable C++. That is MS's typedef.

Comment: I am giving it a try, but then I need to convert the std::wstring to BSTR since my send e-mail function uses BSTR as inputs...

Comment: I am doing like this:

std::wstring firstText ( L"abc" );    
std::wstring secondText ( L"def" );    
std::wstring thirdText ( L"" );    

thirdText += firstText + L"\r\n" + secondText;

but the thirdText is "abc def"....
Am I doing it wrong??? So there is no linefeed...

Comment: @Abe000 you can convert a `std::wstring` to a `BSTR` using [`_bstr_t`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-class?view=vs-2017), or [`SysAllocString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstring) directly. Also, `std::wstring thirdText ( L"" ); thirdText += firstText + ...` should be `std::wstring thirdText = firstText + ...`.  But, either way, there is no way this code snippet can produce the result you claim. Something else in your code has to be converting the linebreak to whitespace afterwards. Probably something in your email code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I guess I need to go through the whole code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same as you would with non-W strings but using the wide string versions of the functions, e.g. (untested)

```
int thirdTextMax = (sizeof(thirdText)/sizeof(thirdText[0]));
swprintf(thirdText, thirdTextMax, L"%s\r\n%s", firstText, secondText);
```

or

```
int firstTextLen = wcslen(firstText);
wcsncpy(thirdText, firstText, thirdTextMax);
wcsncpy(thirdText + firstTextLen, L"\r\n", thirdTextMax - firstTextLen);
wcsncpy(thirdText + firstTextLen + 2, secondText, thirdTextMax - firstTextLen - 2);
```

(There are also the _s versions of these functions to be extra careful about overflowing the buffers but I can't remember if they're in VC2005 or not.)

Comment: Or better, since the question is tagged `c++`, use `std::wstring` instead of `WCHAR[]`, then you can utilize its `operator+=`, or `std::wostringstream`. Use `std::wstring::c_str()` if you need a `wchar_t*`

Comment: Thanks guys,but what is the "thirdTextMax"? Should it be the max length of thirdText which in this example is 500?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry I compute it in the first example from sizeof but not the second.

Comment: @Abe000 Be aware that the wcsncpy variant is quite inefficient: First, you need to iterate over first text to find length, then iterate *again* for copying. wcsncpy fills the whole rest of the array with null characters, but that will be overwritten anyway (except for last call). So you really should prefer the first variant - too bad, though, there's no `snwprintf`... So in *general* (in given case, buffer sizes fit!), I'd go with `swnprintf_s` - ***if*** you insist on arrays, otherwise, see Remy's comment!

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks, I didn't know wcsncpy filled with zeros - it's been years since I looked at this stuff carefully. However AFAICS swprintf already does the 'n' bit by default.

Comment: @Rup Ah, sure, you're right - too much used to the narrow characters, so missed this purely out of my habits... But strncpy behaves alike in this respect.

Comment: This entire *cpy function family (wide or not) has a big design flaw anyway: why return `dest` again? Would have been much more useful if the pointer to the terminating 0 would have been returned - apart from the well known issues (either filling up to many or not terminating at all, if destination too small...).

Comment: @Rup, unfortunately with both solutions, when I send the string as an e-mail, whole text is shown on one line, i.e. somehow it does not work. Even in VC++ watch window I can not see the effect of swprintf...

Comment: Is the string correctly emitted with the CRLF? If you’re constructing an HTML email you’ll need some mark-up e.g. <br> as a line break instead.

Comment: I am sending a simple plain text. In Visual Basic I would just do like this: thirdText  = firstText & Chr(13)  & secondText. There i.e. in VB i use the same send e-mail function & it works perfectly there

Comment: @  Remy Lebeau:    I am doing like this:

std::wstring firstText ( L"abc" );    
std::wstring secondText ( L"def" );    
std::wstring thirdText ( L"" );    

thirdText += firstText + L"\r\n" + secondText;

but the thirdText is "abc def"....
Am I doing it wrong??? So there is no linefeed...

Comment: @Rup: Thank you. I had to change the e-mail format to HTML to get it working. You all have a good weekend! Abe000

Comment: Ah I didn’t think of that. Email clients (like StackOverflow) will often ignore line breaks to try and format text better as paragraphs. Try adding three spaces to end of the first line: that’s the usual convention for ‘don’t combine these two lines’. But HTML works as well of course.

Comment: I already had tried the so called word binding i.e. putting the \r\n between two words or even spaces but somehow it didn't work. For my purpose, I just need to notify 2-3 lines of text, it perfectly works:-) You have a good time. Abe